# Prove that $J$ is an ideal.

Tags: polynomials, ideals

I don't really get this question....isn't $J$ actually $k[x_1,...,x_{n-1}]$ itself?

> Let $I \subset k[x_1...x_{n-1},y]$ be an ideal. For a polynomial $f \in k[x_1,...x_{n-1},y]$, write $f=g_0+g_1y+...+g_my^m$ and denote $g_m \in k[x_1,...,x_{n-1}]$ the leading coefficient of $f$ with respect to $y$. Then show that $$J=\{g \in k[x_1...x_{n-1}]\ |\ \text{there is } f \in I \text{ such that } g \text{ is the leading coefficient of }f\},$$
>   is an ideal.

I am trying to prove it satisfies the definition of an ideal. I am stuck or confused where I have to show that, say $g_i,g_j \in J$ then $g_i-g_j \in I$. So it's closed under subtraction.

But I don't know, If $g_m \in k[x_1...x_{n-1}]$ then, isn't ANY possible polynomial in $k[x_1...x_{n-1}]$ I can dream of possible for any $g_i,g_j$? So well, their subtraction will clearly still be in $k[x_1...x_{n-1}]$ and....isn't $J = k[x_1...x_{n-1}]$ then?

I don't see any restriction on $g_m$ here, it can be every single possible polynomial in $k[x_1...x_{n-1}]$ yes? I don't see why not.

Then the proof seems...rather trivial. As long as $g_i-g_j \in k[x_1...x_{n-1}]$ which it clearly is, it is also in $J$.

Am I right?? I'm quite confused...because I feel like I'm wrong somewhere but i don't see where

Comment: Then show that... what? Aren't you just defining $J$?

Comment: Here $I$ is fixed, so I don't see why we're allowed to get anything we want. You have to work with the polynomials in $I$. Think about $(x_1y) \subset k[x_1,y]$ or something like that.

Comment: I don't know if I got you correctly, but I meant I can get $g_m$ to be any polynomial in $k[x_1...x_{n-1}]$ .... no?

Comment: Why do you think that?

Comment: $g_m \in k[x_1...x_{n-1}]$ by definition, so doesn't that mean this $g_m$ is something in $ k[x_1...x_{n-1}]$? Then,,,I don't really see any restriction on $g_m$...meaning, I don't see any reason why it can't be some of the elements in $ k[x_1...x_{n-1}]$. It is just the leading coefficient of the polynomials of one variable, $y$.

Comment: But you demand that $f$ is an element of $I$.

Comment: And for any $g_i \in k[x_1...x_{n-1}]$, we have $g_iy^i \in k[x_1...x_{n-1},y]$ no? so the lienar combination of such monomials $f$ is also in it...Is there a conterexample I seriously cant think of any

Comment: You're still ignoring any mention of $I$. Why does your $g_iy^i$ have to be in $I$? If $I$ is the whole ring then sure, but otherwise? It just seems like we keep looking past the dependence on the original ideal, which is the whole point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the ideal $I = (x y + 1)$ of the ring $k[x,y]$. Then the ideal $J$ consists only of $g(x) \in k[x]$ which are divisible by $x$. This follows, as every $h \in I$ is of the form

$$h = (x y + 1) (g_m(x)y^m + \cdots + g_1(x) y + g_0(x))$$

In general $J$ is an ideal: if $f_1 = g_1 y^{m_1} + r_1 \in I$ where every power of $y$ in $r$ is less than $m_1$ and similar $f_2 = g_2 y^{m_2} + r_2 \in I$ and without restricting generality $m_2 \geqslant m_1$, then
$g_1 - g_2$ is the leading coefficient of $f_1 y^{m_2-m_1} - f_2$ considered in $k[x_1,\ldots,x_{n-1}][y]$.

Comment: Sorry but what is this $h$? It seems like it's $f$ times the generator of the ideal but I'm not sure what that creates.

Comment: $h$ is an arbitrary element of $I$, which is, by definition of $(x y + 1) = (xy + 1) k[x,y]$ given by the displayed equation.

Comment: oh, okay, i think i got it...thanks!